# Как посчитать моду?

Tags: java, массивы, list, swing

У меня есть некий массив, нужно посчитать моду в данном массиве (вывести какое число повторяется несколько раз в массиве). Вот мой пример кода, но не понимаю, то ли я делаю.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Object sorted = listValue.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
int list = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(listValue));
int max  = 1;
int temp = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < listValue.size(); i++) {

    if (hm.get(listValue) != null) {

        int count = hm.get(listValue);
        count++;
        hm.put(list, count);

        if(count > max) {
           max  = count;
           temp = list;
                                          }
                                        }

          else
          hm.put(list,1);
                                    }
    return temp;
                                }
```

Comment: А что за "мода"? Приведите пример значений `listValue` и ожидаемый результат

Comment: А так, у вас в `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` ключом будет объект, а значением счетчик. Далее, вы перебираете список объектов и меняете значение в словаре: для нового ключа "значение 1", для существующего "текущее значение по ключу + 1"

Comment: к примеру даётся массив: 1 4 8 7 9 4 5. В данном случае необходимо будет вывести число 4, т.к. оно повторяется.

Comment: @gil9red, не совсем поняла Вас. Код, который я приложила, он правильный?

Comment: Мне показался он перемудренный и я не был уверен, что он правильный :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отсортировать и перебрать элементы парами:

```
List<Object> listValue = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 8, 7, 9, 4, 5);
List<Object> sorted = listValue.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i = 1; i < sorted.size(); i++) {
    Object prevValue = sorted.get(i - 1);
    if (prevValue == sorted.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(prevValue);
    }
}
```

Можно посчитать элементы в словаре, так чтобы ключ=элемент, значение=количество, после вывести те, которых значение больше 1:

```
List<Object> listValue = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 8, 7, 9, 4, 5);
Map<Object, Integer> valueByCounter = new HashMap<>();

for (Object value : listValue) {
    Integer counter = valueByCounter.getOrDefault(value, 0);
    counter++;
    valueByCounter.put(value, counter);
}

for (Map.Entry<Object, Integer> entry : valueByCounter.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Еще вариант нахождения дубликатов через сбор значений в списке, тут нужно проверить что если значение если в списке, значит дубликат, иначе добавить его в список:

```
List<Object> listValue = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 8, 7, 9, 4, 5);
List<Object> uniques = new LinkedList<>();

for (Object value : listValue) {
    if (uniques.contains(value)) {
        System.out.println(value);
    } else {
        uniques.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valentina, перебираем список значений, у словаря через метод getOrDefault запрашиваем значения по ключу, если ключа нет, то вернется значение из второго параметра метода, т.е. 0, мы увеличиваем значение на 1 и сохраняем новое, так счетчик работает. Далее перебираем ключ-значение из словаря и выводим только те ключи, у которых значение больше 1

Comment: а если будет несколько в массиве повторяющихся значений: 1 4 8 7 1 8 9, и нужно вывести 1 и 8? как это записать в Вашем 3 коде?

Comment: @Valentina, то выведет и 1 и 8

Comment: попробовала, выводит только 8

Comment: Я проверял на этих данных: `List<Object> listValue = Arrays.asList(1, 8, 7, 9, 4, 5, 1, 8);`

Comment: Подскажите, как записать условие для Вашего 3 кода, что если моды нет в списке, то выходит надпись?

Comment: @Valentina, еще актуально? Я правильно понимаю, что если нет дублирующих значений, то вывести об этом сообщение? Самое простое - сделайте флаг = false, при нахождении дубликата возведите его в true, а после цикла проверьте его значение и выведите сообщение

Comment: а что значит после цикла проверить его значение?

Comment: Смотрите, до цикла заводите переменную `boolean found = false;`, в блоке `if (uniques.contains(value)) {` ставите флаг `found = true;`, а после цикла проверяйте что `if (!found) { действие о том, что дубликатов нет }`

Comment: Спасибо большое!